# Consulta com collection no JPA Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, rest

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dúvida que talvez ajude outras pessoas. Em meu projeto tenho uma entidade veículo, esta entidade possui uma coleção de outra entidade chamada Opcional(Opcionais do veículo), um exemplo de opcional seria Cd Player, Airbag, Alarme e outros. No Repository do veiculo eu tenho um método que busca veículos por modelo e por uma collection de opcionais, algo assim:

```
List<Veiculo> findDistinctByModeloMarcaNomeIgnoreCaseAndOpcionaisNomeIn(String marca, List<String> opcionais);
```

Obs: O veículo esta relacionado com Modelo que esta relacionado com Marca.

Porem, com este método gerado ele me retorna uma lista de veículos que possua pelo menos um dos elementos da lista de opcionais, não é o objetivo. A ideia é que ele me retorne uma lista de veículos que possua todos os elementos da lista opcionais e não apenas um ou outro.

Na procura de uma solução encontrei este tópico:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106207/spring-jpa-query-by-example-collection

Neste tópico é possível ver que um colega nos informa que seria necessário criar um filtro em java, pois não teria como fazer utilizando o Spring Data. Gostaria de saber se existe algum modo mais recomendado de fazer isto, ou se desta forma que foi recomendado seria a melhor opção.

Pessoal desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês! Abraços!

Comment: Tenho um projeto que utiliza Spring Data JPA, fiz algo similar ao que vc quer porém com produtos e categorias, um produto tem várias categorias, quanto mais categorias informo, mais restritiva será a consulta, para resolver isso utilize "Consultas via Specification". É justamente pra atender consultas dinâmicas. Seria algo assim que vc procura?

Comment: Opa amigo, bom dia. Então, não tenho certeza, mas vou procurar sobre Specification, a ideia seria "filtrar" a consulta, para que  me retorne os veículos apenas que correspondem a marca que foi escolhida e aos opcionais que forem selecionados. Então por  exemplo, se o individuo escolher os carros da marca Ford e os opcionais de banco aquecido, Airbag, direção elétrica, a ideia era a consulta me retornar apenas os veículos que são da Ford e possuem estes 3 opcionais e mais outros,

Comment: os que não possuem estes 3 opcionais não aparecem na lista, ai conforme o individuo fosse adicionando mais opcionais para filtrar, a lista de veículos iria diminuindo trazendo apenas os veículos que correspondem aos opcionais.

Comment: Vi sua postagem, isso ai! Pra este tipo de situação Specifications são a melhor abordagem. Com ele por exemplo, vc poderia fazer uma consulta com várias palavras em um único parâmetro, igual as consultas em sites de compra onde quanto mais detalhes, mais refino o resultado. Valeu.

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado pela ajuda José, dei uma olhada nos seus tópicos e isso me deu uma luz ahaha. Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de seguirem com a solução vale lembrar que sou estudante, então não tenho certeza se do modo como foi constituído a solução se ela estará correta, acredito que tem muito a melhorar ainda mas que já é um inicio, espero poder ajudar mais pessoas com esta solução.

Pessoal acredito ter achado uma solução para meu problema seguindo a dica de vocês, primeiramente criei uma classe chamada VeiculoSpecs, nesta classe foi encapsulado a logica para retornar uma Specification que sera utilizado no VeiculoRepository. Lembrando que a ideia era que o usuário informasse a marca do veiculo desejada e os opcionais do mesmo para retornar uma lista de veículos seguindo estes critérios, então no VeiculoSpecs temos um método que faz isso para a gente, conforme é mostrado abaixo:

```
public class VeiculoSpecs {


        public static Specification<Veiculo> findByMarcaAndOpcionais(String marca, List<String> opcionais) {
            return new Specification<Veiculo>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Veiculo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                    if(!marca.isEmpty()) {
                        predicates.add(builder.equal(builder.lower(root.get("modelo").get("marca").get("nome")), marca.toLowerCase()));
                    }

                    if(!opcionais.isEmpty()) {
                        for(String nome: opcionais) {
                            predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.join("opcionais").get("nome")), "%" + nome.toLowerCase() + "%"));

                        }
                    }

                    query.distinct(true);

                    return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[1]));
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

1. É criado uma lista para armazenar os predicates.
2. Ele pega a marca do veiculo informada e verifica quais veículos
   pertencem aquela marca.
3. No FOR ele percorre a lista de opcionais(nomes), que foi recebida
   nos parâmetros do método, e cria uma consulta que sera adicionada na
   lista dos predicates utilizando LIKE para cada opcional(nome) da
   lista.

No repository ele recebe esta Specification no método de buscar todos, lembrando que o repository deve estender a interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<>, como mostrado a seguir:

```
@Repository
public interface VeiculoRepository extends JpaRepository<Veiculo, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Veiculo>{

    List<Veiculo> findAll(Specification<Veiculo> spec);
}
```

Por fim, na classe VeiculoService no método de busca por marca/opcionais é feito a chamada do método no repository de buscar todos passando no parâmetro o resultado do método que esta em VeiculoSpecs passando a marca e a lista de nomes dos opcionais como parâmetro, código:

```
@Service
public class VeiculoService {

    @Autowired
    private VeiculoRepository repo;

    public List<Veiculo> findByMarcaAndOpcionaisSpecification(String marca, List<String> opcionais) {
        return repo.findAll(VeiculoSpecs.findByMarcaAndOpcionais(marca, opcionais));
    }

}
```

Testes **fictícios**:

- Estes testes são apenas para demonstrar como seria +- na pratica.
  Lembrando que neste teste tudo foi simplificado para demonstrar
  apenas o necessário.

  Veiculo v1 = new Veiculo("Ford");
  v1.setOpcionais(Arrays.asList("Airbag, Alarme, Rádio"));

  Veiculo v2 = new Veiculo("Ford");
  v2.setOpcionais(Arrays.asList("Airbag, Alarme"));

No final se o usuário realizar uma busca com objetivo em receber uma lista contendo veículos da marca Ford com os opcionais "Airbag, Alarme, Rádio", ele recebera apenas o veiculo 1. Se ele colocar que quer receber um veículo da marca Ford com os opcionais "Airbag, Alarme" ele vai receber o veiculo 1 e 2.

Comment: Isso ai. Muito bom.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que a anotação @Query() resolve seu problema. Da uma olhada aqui: 
[Video do Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fW6_hY1GXAI&t=277s) (ingles)